# Getting a constant value from a series

Tags: pine-script

I want to assign a constant value to a variable. This value comes from a series. The value is 10 bars back, and must stay constant unless there is a new bar.

I tried this code and lots of variations on it, but it didn't work.

```
//@version=4
study(title = "X", overlay = false)

var x = 0.0
x := valuewhen(barstate.islast, sum(cht_acum[10], 10), 1)

plot(x, title = "X")
```

I don't get a straight line, or I get NA. How to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Version 1

Hard to figure out what you want. This may come close. You can use the Inputs to plot only on the last bar:

```
//@version=4
study(title = "X", overlay = false)
cht_acum = close
plotOnLastBarOnly = input(false)
x = sum(cht_acum[10], 10)
plot(barstate.islast or not plotOnLastBarOnly ? x : na, title = "X")
```

#### Version 2

This version uses the brilliant `Sum()` function from alexgrover found in [Functions Allowing Series As Length - PineCoders FAQ](https://www.tradingview.com/script/kY5hhjA7-Functions-Allowing-Series-As-Length-PineCoders-FAQ/), which accepts a series length. Should be closer to your needs:

```
//@version=4
study("")
Sum(src,p) => a = cum(src), a - a[max(p,0)]
cond = rising(close, 30)
sourceSeries = 1.
var count = 0.
if cond
    count := 1.
else
    count := min(10, count + 1)
total = Sum(sourceSeries, count)
plot(total)
plotchar(cond, "cond", "•", location.top, size = size.tiny)
```

[image]

Comment: It's difficult to explain what I want... Let me try again.

Comment: I want to plot the cumulative of a series for the last 10 bars, ignoring anything before them. I know I can use show_last to hide anything before the last 10 bars, however I want the cumulative to start from zero. So if I have these 10 values at the end of a series => 10, 15, -5, -7, 12, -2, -8, 18, 4, -7 my cumulative to plot should be 10, 25, 20, 13, 25, 23, 15, 33, 37, 30.

Comment: If I use cum(x) I get cumulative from the beginning of the series, but I want to start from zero.
If I use sum(x, 10) I get the sliding sum of the last 10 values which is not what I want.
I tried using max_bars_back but it didn't work either.
I tried cum(x) - sum(x,10) but again not what I want.
Then I tried
var x = 0.0
x := valuewhen(barstate.islast, sum(cht_acum[10], 10), 1)
but got only na or random numbers...

Comment: Thx for the explanations. Edited answer.