# Boolean - is this bar 10 periods back from latest?

Tags: pine-script

I want to use the last 10 bars in a chart for a counter. The counter uses true/false to start counting. Currently I'm manually inputting the bar's number and number of bars to the last. So if the last bar is number 1017, and I want to display the last 10 bars I'd use:

```
start_bar = 1007
no_of_bars = 10
cond = bar_index == start_bar
```

However every time I go on a different chart I need to find the bar number of the latest bar, and manually input start_bar.

How can I do this programmatically? I tried using:

- bar_index - 10 or bar_index[10]
- barstate.islast ? bar_index - 10 :na
- barssince(some boolean)

Then putting the result in a global variable to use in the boolean. No success. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make a calculation requiring only the last 10 bars then your best option is to use a loop.

```
for i = 0 to 9
```

The result of interest would be displayed at the last bar. If what you need is just showing the last 10 bars of a series you need to use `show_last = 10` in the `plot` function.

Comment: Hi @alexgrover, I'm running a loop based on your sum function as suggested to me by LucF in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62052149/getting-a-constant-value-from-a-series).


`//@version=4
study("test", overlay = false)
start_bar = 995
no_of_bars = 23
cum_sum(src, p) => a = cum(src), a - a[max(p, 0)]
cond = bar_index == start_bar
sourceSeries = 1.
var count = 0.
if cond
    count := 1.
else
    count := min(no_of_bars, count + 1)
total = cum_sum(sourceSeries, count)
plot(total, show_last = no_of_bars)`

Comment: I'm using
`start_bar = 995
cond = bar_index == start_bar`

as the trigger, but would like to have that automated because the bar number changes depending on what chart or timeframe I'm on. I'd like to say start from 10 bars back.

Comment: So if I understand you want the cumulative sum of the last 10 bars, that's right?

Comment: Yes, I want to ignore or hide anything before 10 bars, then start counting cumulatively. Important I start from zero.

Comment: Well that's still tricky, there is no easy way to get in advance the total number of bars in a chart (as far as I am aware), you could use security with `lookahead=true` in order to get the number of bars in advance, this method might work but will repaint.

Comment: The closest I can get is creating an indicator "My Script" with this code

`cond = barstate.islast ? bar_index : na
plot(cond, offset = - 9)`

Then feeding the results of the above "My Script" indicator to the next indicator below using the code

`ExternalIndicator = input(close, "External Indicator")
cond = bar_index == ExternalIndicator`

I have to manually change External Indicator to "My Script" every time. But can't subtract 10 bars from ExternalIndicator or it doesn't work... and this is more work than manually inputting the last bar for each chart, so not the time saver I need